# Bluetooth detected only when AC plugged in

Tags: bluetooth, mx-linux

I have a dual-boot system with MX Linux 23/KDE and Windows. After updating and upgrading my fresh MX Linux install, I encountered an issue with the Bluetooth. It seems that the Bluetooth adapter is only detected when my laptop is powered on via the adapter. If I boot without being connected to power, or if I unplug the laptop after booting with power, the Bluetooth seems to turn off or go to sleep, displaying "no adapter found". 
Tried:

1.I've tried reinstalling blueZ without success. 
2. Edited the bluetooth config files: main.conf --> discoverabletimeout=0, Alwayspairable=true, Pairabletimeout=0. 
  Input.conf --> Idletimeout=0. 
3.Added USB powersave rules in etc/udev/rules.d as per some suggestions here. 
4. Fastboot is turned off from BIOS.

Does anyone have suggestions to resolve this? My network card is Realtek 8822CE. My system details:

````
  Kernel: 6.4.0-1mx-ahs-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
    Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.5 Distro: MX-23_KDE_x64 Libretto July 31  2023
    base: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Alpha 15 A3DD v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16U6 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: E16U6AMS.112 date: 07/23/2020
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 35.8 Wh (90.2%) condition: 39.7/51.6 Wh (77.0%)
    volts: 11.9 min: 10.9 model: MSI BIF0_9 status: charging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
    bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen/Zen+ note: check rev: 1 cache: L1: 384 KiB
    L2: 2 MiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1354 high: 1400 min/max: 1400/2300 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 1397 2: 1222 3: 1400 4: 1400 5: 1397 6: 1400 7: 1222 8: 1400
    bogomips: 36729
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: RDNA-1 bus-ID: 03:00.0
  Device-2: AMD Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: GCN-5 bus-ID: 07:00.0
    temp: 65.0 C
  Device-3: Chicony HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-1:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: AMD Radeon Vega 10 Graphics
    (raven LLVM 15.0.6 DRM 3.52 6.4.0-1mx-ahs-amd64) direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 03:00.1
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor driver: snd_pci_acp3x
    v: kernel bus-ID: 07:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 07:00.6
  API: ALSA v: k6.4.0-1mx-ahs-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: AzureWave driver: rtw_8822ce v: N/A port: f000 bus-ID: 05:00.0
  IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel
    port: e000 bus-ID: 06:00.0
  IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-2.4:5
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0
    lmp-v: 5.1
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 216.24 GiB (18.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KBG40ZNV256G KIOXIA
    size: 238.47 GiB temp: 33.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM048-2E7172 size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 104.2 GiB used: 29.47 GiB (28.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 296 MiB used: 28.6 MiB (9.7%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 65.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
  GPU: device: amdgpu temp: 65.0 C device: amdgpu temp: 49.0 C fan: 65535
Info:
  Processes: 314 Uptime: 14m Memory: 13.56 GiB used: 3.12 GiB (23.0%)
  Init: SysVinit runlevel: 5 Compilers: N/A Packages: 2683 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.26```
````